# Get total in HH:MM format from the dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
CREATE procedure St_Proc_GetUserReportforCurrentDayTask                        
@userID int                        
as                        
    Begin                        
        set NoCount on;                        
        DECLARE @TODAY DATE                          
        SET @TODAY = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)                        
        select  CONVERT(VARCHAR,production.CalendarDate,101) + RIGHT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,production.CalendarDate , 100 ) ,7) as Date,                         
        RegionAndProjectInfo.RegionProjectName as Region ,                        
        County.CountyName as County,                        
        WorkType.WorkTypeName as WorkType,                        
        Task.TaskName as Task,            
        Production.VolumeProcessed as 'Volumes Processed',                        
        Production.TimeSpent as 'Duration'                        
        from Production                         
        inner join RegionAndProjectInfo                        
        on                        
        RegionAndProjectInfo.RegionProjectID=Production.RegionProjectID                        
        inner join County                        
        on                         
        County.CountyID=Production.CountyID                        
        inner join WorkType                        
        on                        
        WorkType.WorkTypeID=Production.WorkTypeID                        
        inner join Task                        
        on                        
        Task.TaskID=Production.TaskID                        
        where Production.UserID=@userID and CalendarDate >= @TODAY                        
    End
```

From the above Stored Procedure i am filling a Dataset.After that i am binding this Dataset to a grid view.
In the dataset ,the Column Duration contains Data in HH:MM Format(example-01:00,12:45,02:59 etc).Is there a way that i can get the total of Duration in HH:MM format from the dataset itself.I dont want to query again from the Database to get the Sum of the Duration.

Comment: So duration is a varchar field?

Comment: Yes.I had used duration as varchar because it is having data in HH:Mm format. Example 01:00,12:45,02:59 etc

Comment: Ok, then my answer should help you, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using at least SQL-Server 2008, you should use `Time` datatype to represent a .NET `TimeSpan`.

To get it to work with a varchar-column, i would use   `Linq-To-DataSet`, for example:

```
var timeSpans = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new {
        DurHour   = r.Field<String>("Duration").Split(':')[0],
        DurMinute = r.Field<String>("Duration").Split(':')[1]
    })
    .Select(x => new TimeSpan(int.Parse(x.DurHour), int.Parse(x.DurMinute), 0));

Console.WriteLine("Total time in minutes: {0}", timeSpans.Sum(ts=>ts.TotalMinutes));
```

But that is only  a workaround, actually you should really avoid to store a timespan in a varchar column, use varchar only for text and nothing else.

In SQL-Server 2005 (or other dbms) you could also use two columns, one for the start `DateTime` and one for the end `DateTime`.

Comment: This is the first time , i used Linq and now get some idea also after reading it. Thanks a lot to realize me the importance of Linq and i had started learning it.