# Get Total of a column from Dataset in Time Format(HH:MM) using C# without using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to get the total of a column from a dataset without using a LINQ Query?

```
CREATE procedure St_Proc_GetUserReportforCurrentDayTask                        
@userID int                        
as                        
    Begin                        
        set NoCount on;                        
        DECLARE @TODAY DATE                          
        SET @TODAY = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)                        
        select  CONVERT(VARCHAR,production.CalendarDate,101) + RIGHT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,production.CalendarDate , 100 ) ,7) as Date,                         
        RegionAndProjectInfo.RegionProjectName as Region ,                        
        County.CountyName as County,                        
        WorkType.WorkTypeName as WorkType,                        
        Task.TaskName as Task,            
        Production.VolumeProcessed as 'Volumes Processed',                        
        Production.TimeSpent as 'Duration'                        
        from Production                         
        inner join RegionAndProjectInfo                        
        on                        
        RegionAndProjectInfo.RegionProjectID=Production.RegionProjectID                        
        inner join County                        
        on                         
        County.CountyID=Production.CountyID                        
        inner join WorkType                        
        on                        
        WorkType.WorkTypeID=Production.WorkTypeID                        
        inner join Task                        
        on                        
        Task.TaskID=Production.TaskID                        
        where Production.UserID=@userID and CalendarDate >= @TODAY                        
    End
```

From the above stored procedure, I am filling a Dataset. After that, I am binding this Dataset to a grid view. In the dataset, the column `Duration` contains data in an HH:MM Format (example - 01:00, 12:45, 02:59, etc). Is there a way that I can get the total of `Duration` in `HH:MM` format from the dataset itself? I don't want to query again from the database to get the `SUM` of `Duration`. I had posted this question already [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543423/get-total-in-hhmm-format-from-the-dataset) but the solution was to use a LINQ query, which I dont want to use.

Comment: So you are not a LINQ guy... bad user!

Comment: Yes :( Today i realized the importance of Linq too. Planning to get training ASAP

Comment: Note that there's no reason for you to not use LINQ.  Don't confuse LINQ with LINQ to SQL.  You can use LINQ to objects on your dataset and still have your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious why you don't want to use Linq, but I digress...

Here's an un-linq-y version using loops:

```
double total = 0;
foreach(DataRow r in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{

    var DurHour = r["Duration"].ToString().Split(':')[0];
    var DurMinute = r["Duration"].ToString().Split(':')[1];
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(DurHour), int.Parse(DurMinute), 0);
    total += ts.TotalMinutes;
}

Console.WriteLine("Total time in minutes: {0}", total);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now my problem is resolved by using your code and side by side, i had started learning Linq as i dont want to be a Bad programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DataTable.Compute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to do sums, however, it won't know how to deal with duration as HH:MM. You'd need to provide another colum in your SELECT that converts HH:MM to a numeric type, then convert it back to HH:MM in your code after summing.

If you can change the database schema I'd store duration as ticks in an int or bigint column. This let's you easily convert to a TimeSpan on the .NET side. It also allows you to more easily perform sums and range checks in SQL. If you need to be able to convert TimeSpans to and from ticks in SQL, you can use the functions below that I wrote. **I've had to insert some random underscore (_) characters to get my answer to submit. (For some reason saving times out without them.) They'll need to be removed for the code to work. Sorry about that.**

To get ticks from a string representation of a time string:

```
/*
[-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff] 

"-" 
 A minus sign, which indicates a negative time interval. No sign is included for a positive time span.

"d" 
 The number of days in the time interval. This element is omitted if the time interval is less than one day. 

"hh" 
 The number of hours in the time interval, ranging from 0 to 23. 

"mm" 
 The number of minutes in the time interval, ranging from 0 to 59. 

"ss" 
 The number of seconds in the time interval, ranging from 0 to 59. 

"fffffff" 
 Fractional seconds in the time interval. This element is omitted if the time interval does not include fractional seconds. If present, fractional seconds are always expressed using seven decimal digits.
*/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseTimeSpanString]
(
    @timespan varchar(26) 
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @hourStart int
    DECLARE @minuteStart int
    DECLARE @secondStart int
    DECLARE @ticks bigint

    SET @hourStart = CHAR INDEX('.', @timeSpan) + 1
    SET @minuteStart = CHAR INDEX(':', @timeSpan) + 1
    SET @secondStart = CHAR INDEX(':', @timespan, @minuteStart) + 1
    SET @ticks = 0

    IF (@hourStart < @minuteStart)
    BEGIN
        SET @ticks = CON_VERT(int, LEFT(@timespan, @hourstart - 2)) * 864000000000
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @hourStart = 1
    END

    SET @ticks = @ticks + CON_VERT(int, SUBSTRING(@timespan, @hourStart, @minuteStart - @hourStart - 1)) * 36000000000
    SET @ticks = @ticks + CON_VERT(int, SUBSTRING(@timespan, @minuteStart, @secondStart - @minuteStart - 1)) * 600000000
    SET @ticks = @ticks + CON_VERT(decimal(9,7), SUBSTRING(@timespan, @secondStart, LEN(@timeSpan) - @secondStart)) * 10000000.0

    RETURN @ticks
END

GO
```

To get a string representation of a TimeSpan from ticks:

```
/*
[-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff] 

"-" 
 A minus sign, which indicates a negative time interval. No sign is included for a positive time span.

"d" 
 The number of days in the time interval. This element is omitted if the time interval is less than one day. 

"hh" 
 The number of hours in the time interval, ranging from 0 to 23. 

"mm" 
 The number of minutes in the time interval, ranging from 0 to 59. 

"ss" 
 The number of seconds in the time interval, ranging from 0 to 59. 

"fffffff" 
 Fractional seconds in the time interval. This element is omitted if the time interval does not include fractional seconds. If present, fractional seconds are always expressed using seven decimal digits.
*/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTimeSpanString]
(
    @ticks bigint
)
RETURNS varchar(26)
AS
BEGIN
    DECL_ARE @timeSpanString varchar(26)

    IF @ticks < 0
    BEGIN
        SET @timeSpanString = '-'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @timeSpanString = ''
    END

    SET @ticks = ABS(@ticks)

    -- Days
    SET @timeSpanString = @timeSpanString + CON_VERT(varchar(26), FLOOR(@ticks / 864000000000.0)) + '.'
    SET @ticks = @ticks % 864000000000

    -- Hours
    SET @timeSpanString = @timeSpanString + CON_VERT(varchar(26), FLOOR(@ticks / 36000000000.0)) + ':'
    SET @ticks = @ticks % 36000000000

    -- Minutes
    SET @timeSpanString = @timeSpanString + CON_VERT(varchar(26), FLOOR(@ticks / 600000000.0)) + ':'
    SET @ticks = @ticks % 600000000

    --Seconds
    DECLARE @seconds decimal(9,7)
    SET @seconds = @ticks / 10000000.0
    SET @timeSpanString = @timeSpanString + CON_VERT(varchar(26), @seconds)

    RETURN @timeSpanString
END

GO
```