# Dataset Sorting using C# on a column with Datetime datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a dataset (Dataset ds) and below you can find the field with demo data inside the dataset.
In my Dataset , their is column with name Date (Datatype- DateTime) and i want to sort this column.I cant do the sorting from SQl because the Dataset is a merge of 2 Different Dataset.
Please help me that how i do the sorting in dataset.

```
Date              Volume

07/19/201211:30AM  12

07/18/201201:30PM  13

07/17/201203:30PM  22
```

Comment: Do you want to [avoid Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546318/get-total-of-a-column-from-dataset-in-time-formathhmm-using-c-sharp-without-u) again? Otherwise you can use a simple `OrderBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date"))`

Comment: No, Now i started using Linq. Its good but currently i am in learning stage .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a simple `Linq-To-DataSet` approach:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> orderedRows = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date"));
```

Now you can use that as `DataSource` or enumerate it in a `foreach`. If you need to materialize it, you might want to create a new `DataTable` from it:

```
DataTable tblOrdered = orderedRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [create a data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719810%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) view from your `data-set`.

Then you can use the [DataView.Sort Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to sort your data.

eg.

```
   DataView myDataView = DT.DefaultView;  
   myDataView.Sort = "Date DESC";
```

Read more about [Introduction to Filtering and Sorting in Datasets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b51xae2y%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Code throws error, it should be like this myDataView.Sort = "Date  DESC"; but it is also not giving accurate sorted result.

Comment: Yes it is. it was extra ",". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using Dataview you can sort your Datatable.
Just put your Datatable in Dataview 
Look at the following example :

You have dtlog table which having two columns one is date and another one is detials.
you want to sort your datatable by date column.

```
DataTable dtlog = new DataTable();
dtlog.Columns.Add("date");
dtlog.Columns.Add("details");
```

1.create dataview and put your datatable in view

```
DataView dtview = new DataView(dtlog);
string sortstring = "date DESC"; // sorting in descending manner 
dtview.Sort = sortstring;
```

2.Create another table where you can save your sorted dataview

```
DataTable dtsort =dtview.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by a DataView. If your column which is holding datetime is a datetime column

```
DataView dv = DataTable.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "DateTime-ColumnName ASC";
```

It will not work on string column holding datetime as string.

Comment: This is not giving accurate result.

Comment: The column in the DataTable must be defined as typeof(DateTime).

Answer (score 0):

The DataView of a DataTable have a sort property please pass the column name to it

E.g.

```
dataSet1.Table[0].DefautlView.Sort = "ColumnName";
```

default sort is by ascending order

For more see link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I find my solucion is add more columns to Datatable where we can save each part of a `DateTime`:

```
Tabla.Columns.Add("year", typeof(DateTime));
Tabla.Columns.Add("month", typeof(DateTime));
Tabla.Columns.Add("day", typeof(DateTime));
```

then we can `sort` our datatable with a `DataView`:

```
DataView myDataView = DT.DefaultView;

case 1: ASC
  myDataView.Sort = "year asc, month asc, day asc"; 

case 2: DESC
  myDataView.Sort = "year desc, month desc, day desc";


Tabla = myDataViwe.toTable();
```

result is our datatable sorted for a dateTime

Answer (score 0):

It worked for Me:

```
 dataTableEmpSurvey.DefaultView.Sort = "SNO";
 var dataTableSorted = dataTableEmpSurvey.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/219205/How-To-Sort-Datatable-in-csharp-net